# DSP - Converting a sampled signal from real samples to complex samples and vice versa

Tags: algorithm, signal-processing

How can I convert baseband sampled signal from real-valued samples to complex-valued samples (real,imaginary) and vice-versa.

My samples are integers, and I'm looking for a fast (but accurate) conversion algorithms.

A C++ sample code (real, not complex ;-) would be more than welcome.

**Edit**: IPP code will be much welcome.

**Edit:** I'm looking for a method that will convert *n* real-samples to *n/2* complex-samples and vice-versa, without affecting the bandwidth.

Comment: I don't think this question means anything unless you describe the semantics of the conversion you want to do. You can treat your samples as complex already, with an implicit imaginary part of 0. But presumably you want to apply some kind of transform - in which case, you need to say what it is.

Comment: For DSP algorithms (like filtering, frequency shifting, etc.) - many implementations are designed for complex samples, while others are designed for real samples. Since a complex representation requires only half of the number of samples that a real representation requires for the same data - Just setting the imaginary part to 0 is not the solution.

Comment: Usually complex time domain samples arise when there's a mixer somewhere in the signal processing chain.  If you have just one of the in-phase and quadrature components, in general you can't recover the other.

Answer (score 11):

Adding zeros as the imaginary is conceptually the first step in what you want to do.  Initially you have a real only signal that looks like this in the frequency domain:

```
           [r0, r1, r2, r3, ...]

                           /-~--------\
                         DC            +Fs/2
```

If you stuff it with zeros for the imaginary value, you'll see that you really have both positive and negative frequencies as mirror images:

```
           [r0 + 0i, r1 + 0i, r2 + 0i, r3 + 0i, ...]

             /--------~-\  /-~--------\
          -Fs/2          DC            +Fs/2
```

Next, you multiply that signal in the time domain by a complex tone at -Fs/4 (tuning the signal).  Your signal will look like

```
           ----~-\ /-~--------\ /------
                        DC
```

So now, you filter out the center half and you get:

```
           ________/-~--------\________
                        DC
```

Then you decimate by two and you end up with:

```
                   /-~--------\
```

Which is what you want.

All of these steps can be performed efficiently in the time domain.  If you pay attention to all of the intermediate steps, you'll notice that there are many places where you're multiplying by 0, +1, -1, +i, or -i.  Furthermore, the half band low pass filter will have a lot of zeros and some symmetry to exploit.  Since you know you're going to decimate by 2, you only have to calculate the samples you intend to keep.  If you work through the algebra, you'll find a lot of places to simplify it for a clean and fast implementation.

Ultimately, this is all equivalent to a Hilbert transform, but I think it's much easier to understand when you decompose it into pieces like this.

Converting back to real from complex is similar.  You'll stuff it with zeroes for every other sample to undo the decimation.  You'll filter the complex signal to remove an alias you just introduced.  You'll tune it up by Fs/4, and then throw away the imaginary component.  (Sorry, I'm all ascii-arted out... :-)

Note that this conversion is lossy near the boundaries.  You'd have to use an infinite length filter to do it perfectly.

Comment: Why is not just enough to frequency-shift Fs/4 and then filter? Why is useful to add the null imaginary part and decimate?

Comment: @tashuhka, this is my interpretation:

1. when you add the zeros to the imaginary part you are basically looking at your signal as complex signal. By doing this you continue to have the same information but are now in possession of the tools allowed in the complex space.

2. Regarding the decimation, you are throwing away information that is not needed to represent the same information. In this case you have a sampling freq that no longer needs to be that high. Decimation will lower the sampling freq to the minimum required.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create a complex vector with a strictly real spectrum, just add an imaginary component of 0.0 to every sample.  Depending on your data format, this may be as easy as creating a double length memory array, zeroing it, and copying from every element of the source into every other element of the destination.

If you want to convert a complex vector containing complex data (non-zero imaginary components above your required minimum noise floor) into a real vector, you will need to double your bandwidth in order to not lose information, which may or may not make sense, unless you are modulating, demodulating or filtering the signal.

If you want to produce a one-sided signal with a complex spectrum from a real vector, you can use a Hilbert transform (or filter) to create an imaginary component with the same spectrum but conjugate phase (except for DC).  This would probably not be both fast and accurate.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if that is what you're looking for but you might want to check the [Hilbert Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_transform), which can be used to find the [analytic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_signal) representation of real-valued signals, i.e., a signal with the same amount of information but with no negative frequency components.

Such representation is mostly useful in Digital Signal Processing techniques employing Spectral Shifting such as [Single Sideband Modulation](http://www.mathworks.com/products/signal/examples.html?file=/products/demos/shipping/signal/hilberttransformdemo.html), an efficient form of Amplitude Modulation (AM) that uses half the bandwidth used by the raw AM.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have enough points to vote zml up yet, but his is clearly the right answer.  The Hilbert transform essentially converts your real-valued signal into its more natural domain, where the components of sound are complex "phasors" rather than sine waves.  It does this by essentially chopping of half of the Fourier spectrum, which involves a single choice of "helicity" (i.e. cw vs ccw) but allows you to do things like perfectly pitch shift by multiplying by a single phasor.  The possibilities are endless, and I hope this complex representation of audio catches on!

Answer (score 0):

Intel Performance Primitives (IPP) has a function which does exactly this.

From their documentation:

> The ippsHilbert function computes a complex analytic signal,
> which contains the original real signal as its real part and
> computed Hilbert transform as its imaginary part.

https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/ipp-dev-reference/top/volume-1-signal-and-data-processing/transform-functions/hilbert-transform-functions/hilbert.html#hilbert